# Laravel Blade - Advantage of @slot/@component vs @include?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.4 Blade introduced the concept of components & slots - but I can't see what they add over the traditional @include. As I understand, with component/slots, you do:

In template component-tpl.blade.php:

```
<div class='container'>
  <h1>{{$slot1}}</h1>
  <h2>{{$slot2}}</h2>
</div>
```

Using slots in page template, you do:

```
@component('component-tpl')
  @slot('slot1')
    The content of Slot 1
  @endslot
  @slot('slot2')
    The content of Slot 2
  @endslot
@endcomponent
```

What functionality does that provide over the older:

```
@include('component-tpl',['slot1'=>'The content of Slot 1',
'slot2'=>"The content of Slot 2"])
```

using the exact same 'component-tpl.blade.php' Blade template?

What am I missing?  Thanks for any insights.

Chris

Comment: `@component` seems nice if you are starting a new project but if one already has an existing project that is already using a multitude of `@include`, then it seems like it would be chaos to try and remember which pieces are `@component` and which pieces are `@include`.

Answer (score 72):

<s>As stated, there's no functional difference</s> I was incorrect - see [benjaminhull's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544129/2596564) for details on variable scoping and passing blade syntax code. The following still holds for basic usage, though.

If a slot could contain HTML, then using a component will give a cleaner syntax in your blade files.

```
@component('test')
   <strong>This text has html</strong>
@endcomponent
```

versus

```
@include('test', ['slot' => '<strong>This text has HTML</strong>'])
```

Equally, if a component has no slots, then an include may be preferred:

```
@include('test')
```

versus

```
@component('test')
@endcomponent
```

Comment: This is a much more useful explanation than simply referencing the docs (which frustratingly don't give any helpful use-cases). I've just picked up Laravel a couple weeks ago and am working my first project. My reason for searching this is exactly the example you provided. I have HTML that i don't care to stringify or mess with `ob_start(); ... return ob_get_clean()`.

Comment: This is a great example. I'm struggling to simplify a complex application by building inter-connected blade layouts and this distinction is really helping me distinguish between sections and components.

Comment: For those interested, please take a look at DavidHyogo's answer. He provides an excelent point that should be considered.

Comment: "there's no functional difference" - this isn't true. See mine and other answers. Respectfully, please update your answer since it is not correct.

Answer (score 28):

There are two key differences.

### 1. Variable scope

As described in @DavidHyogo's answer, a component only sees variables explicitly passed to it. So you have to give it all variables like so...

```
@component('my-component', ['foo' => 'bar', 'etc' => 'etc'])
```

Whereas an include will adopt **all variables** from the global/current scope by default - unless you define an explicit set of variables to pass it, which then becomes local scope again.

```
{{-- This include will see all variables from the global/current scope --}}
@include('my-component')

{{-- This include will only see the variables explicitly passed in --}}
@include('my-component', ['foo' => 'bar', 'etc' => 'etc'])
```

### 2. Component's {{ $slot }} vs include's {{ $var }}

When using a {{ $slot }} in a component, you can give it blade syntax code e.g...

```
{{-- alert.blade.php --}}
<div class="alert">{{ $slot }}</div>
```

---

```
@component('alert')
    <div>Hello {{ $name }} @include('welcome-message')</div>
@endcomponent
```

Note how the slot will receive html AND blade syntax code and just deal with it.

This is not possible with includes because you can only pass variables into includes...

```
{{-- alert.blade.php --}}
<div class="alert">{{ $slot }}</div>
```

---

```
@include('alert', ['slot' => "I CAN'T PASS IN BLADE SYNTAX HERE!"])
```

*It could be done in a more hacky way by grabbing a fresh view() helper and passing it some variables to compile the output we want to pass into the slot, but this is what components are for.*

Answer (score 24):

I think I've tracked down another crucial difference. For instance, from the documentation for 5.4:

> Blade's @include directive allows you to include a Blade view from within another view. All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view:

As far as I can tell, components have a different scope from a containing view and so the variables available to the parent view are not available within the component. You need to pass a variable to a component like this:

```
@component('alert', ['foo' => 'bar'])
@endcomponent
```

This discussion is related to this problem:
[Use variables inside the Markdown Mailables](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/use-variables-inside-the-markdown-mailables)

Comment: This is good, but there is more to it still. Check my answer above.

Answer (score 7):

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots) says:

> Components and slots provide similar benefits to sections and
>   layouts; however, **some may find the mental model of components and
>   slots easier to understand**.

Comment: I've read the documentation too, and that sentence didn't really help me distinguish between the two. I think Rick's really helps to unpack these two approaches with a very practical example.

Comment: That is about "Components and slots" vs "sections and layouts"; not about "includes"

Answer (score 0):

For me most important thing is `component` needs a `class`. So when I need just a simplest reusable part of html (blade) there is no need to create blade file + php file, just simple `@include` with `subview` is enough ;)

Comment: Components do not need classes, you can have just a blade file. They also don't need a blade file and can have just a class.

Comment: Similar to inline components, anonymous components provide a mechanism for managing a component via a single file. However, anonymous components utilize a single view file and have no associated class. Source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#anonymous-components